# Use of "ahoy" before "hello"

Tags: british-english

The word *hello* seems to have become popular with the coming of the telephone. Did our ancestors greet each other with *ahoy* before that?

Comment: Isn't "ahoy" a nautical term? :-) What does your research show?

Comment: *"Dr. Livingstone, I presume?"*

Comment: Times have moved on. It seems to me that nearly everyone under 50 says *"Hey"* today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Greetings are subject to extreme variation by locality and subculture. Take my word for it: "Hello" is alive and well.

Answer (score 6):

[Hello](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hello), with that spelling, was used in publications as early as 1833. People in the 1830's said hello to [attract attention](http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2011/02/17/133785829/a-shockingly-short-history-of-hello)

> Hello, what do you think you're doing?

or to express surprise

> Hello, what have we here?

Hello didn't become "hi" until the telephone arrived.

**[Ahoy](http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2011/02/17/133785829/a-shockingly-short-history-of-hello)** has been around longer — at least 100 years longer — than hello. It was a nautical greeting, derived from the Dutch "hoi," meaning "hello." Alexander Graham Bell (inventor of the telephone) felt so strongly about "ahoy" he used it in answering his telephone (except for the first time, when he expressed surprise with *Hello!*) for the rest of his life.

So does "Monty" Burns of *the Simpsons*. Mr. Burns regularly answers his phone with, [Ahoy-hoy](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SWleZY-8evw), a coinage properly used *to greet or get the attention of small sloop-rigged coasting ship.*

Hello became very popular when the first phone books (thanks to [Thomas Edison](http://www.nytimes.com/1992/03/05/garden/great-hello-mystery-is-solved.html)) officially sanctioned "Hello" as the greeting upon answering the phone. (They also, in *Way To End A Phone Conversation*, recommended: "*That is all*.")

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, hello is an alteration of *hallo, hollo,* which came from Old High German *halâ, holâ*, emphatic imperative of *halôn, holôn* to fetch, **used especially in hailing a ferryman.** From The Rime of the Ancient Mariner (1798)

> And the good south wind still blew behind,
>   But no sweet bird did follow,
>   Nor any day for food or play
>   Came to the mariners' **hollo**

Bill Bryson (Mother Tongue) says that "hello" comes from Old English hál béo þu ("Hale be thou", or "whole be thou", meaning a wish for good health).