# Why is the word 'Hello' used frequently when starting a phone call?

Tags: etymology

Why is the word 'Hello' used universally to begin a phone call? What was the origin of it?

Comment: It's nothing like universal. It's common in the United States, but there are other conventions.

Answer (score 3):

Because we liked it better than "Ahoy" which was the other proposal.

[Origin of Hello](http://www.npr.org/blogs/krulwich/2011/02/17/133785829/a-shockingly-short-history-of-hello)

Comment: I so want to upvote for the fun of it, yet I won't as I don't want to encourage something that should be a comment... But thanks for the laugh.

Comment: It is an actual fact, see the link.

Comment: And since you edited, link answers are frowned upon. Can you properly quote the important bits?

Comment: I summarized it with the first line.

Comment: @haylem This is a fact.  The original proposal by Bell was *ahoy*.  Don't be pedantic.

Comment: @DavidM: I'm not pedantic: a statement can make me laugh and still be true, and  the reference is good (although sadly devoid of links to the material it quotes). I'm just arguing the state of the answer. I come here for researched answers, not to go on a click quest.

Comment: @haylem If you don't like the answer, research it and answer yourself. Don't attempt an inappropriate edit to someone else's answer.   That was not a link only answer. It was a short (correct) answer with an explanation link.    If you don't like it down vote and move on.

Comment: @DavidM: I didn't attempt an edit, I did downvote, and I was just stating out why, which is the polite and constructive thing to do. Seems pretty normal to me. About answering myself: do you go about answering all the questions for which you don't like exsting answers? Also stealing away OldCat's answer would be rude, in that case, as he was clearly first. I don't really see a problem here.

Comment: @DavidM: Apart from the fact the question is a [duplicate](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/143056/use-of-ahoy-before-hello) already and shouldn't even be answered here, especially when a better answer was given in the other thread, which uses (amongst others) the reference used by OldCat.

Comment: @haylem I owe you an apology.  I thought you were the one who suggested the edit.  I reviewed it and see I was mistaken.  In any case, the answer was correct, but a bit flip.  I felt your comment pedantic (partially because of my incorrect assumption, but,) because you had already said your piece in the first comment.

Comment: @DavidM: Thanks. But don't worry, I don't mind. My fault for not being explicit enough in my first comment. Plus I'm probably too used to P.SE and tend to be a bit too "by the book" (or in that case, hep/FAQ"). In my view this question should have been closed by a mod a long time ago already, as it's an obvious duplicate and adds nothing to the site.

Comment: @haylem That is probably true.  But, I never blame the answerer for not knowing that it is a dupe.  I don't know about you, but I don't search the question terms before answering.

Comment: @DavidM: I don't always either, but I should. And I'd expect a 2K user to do it. But like I said, might be because I'm used to higher volumes were dups of recurring questions are really annoying.

Comment: @haylem The onus for avoiding dupes should be on the questioner not the answerer.  (And, perhaps the mods, although they have their work cut out for them already.)